# How to add a UIActivityIndicatorView in UIAlertView using ios7?

Tags: uialertview, uiactivityindicatorview, ios7

I am trying to figure out how to create dialogs with progress indicator on ios7.

In my old (works on ios6) code I used:

// ... init alertview ...

```
indicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(125, 55 + hlines, 30, 30)];
int height = self.frame.size.height + indicator.frame.size.height - 20;
[alert addSubview:indicator];
indicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge;
[indicator startAnimating];

[alert setFrame:CGRectMake(self.frame.origin.x, self.frame.origin.y, self.frame.size.width, height)];
```

Any idea?

Comment: From the documentation: "You cannot customize the appearance of alert views."  (https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/UIKitUICatalog/UIAlertView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012857-UIAlertView-SW1)

Comment: You should create your own UIAlertView-like UIView subclass... if you mess with the elements / subviews of UIAlertView directly, you (or the client / employer paying you) might be unpleasantly surprised later on if Apple changes the internal structure of UIAlertView.

Comment: I can't discuss an iOS 7 solution to your problem on stack overflow without violating the non-disclosure agreement.  I suggest you post your question to [Apple's own developer forum](https://devforums.apple.com/).  You might also want to watch the [“Building User Interfaces for iOS 7” video from WWDC 2013](https://developer.apple.com/wwdc/videos/index.php?id=201), starting at 27m40s.  And then read [this port on Apple's forum](https://devforums.apple.com/message/833664#833664).

Comment: As per other related questions/answers, I am using MBProgressHUD